# How to below a regex for choosing a single digit in angular forms sync validator

Tags: regex, angular, angular-forms

I am currently using the following regex pattern:

```
Validators.pattern("^[1-4]*$")
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to produce a valid state if the digits 1-4 are entered and invalid state if anything else is submitted.
Thing is, if I submit let's say 11, it still counts it as valid.
How do I need to change the regex around to meet the above requirements?

Comment: You can omit the quantifier `*` to match a single digit from 1 to 4 `^[1-4]$`

Comment: `Validators.pattern("[1-4]")` will only match a string consising of one char, `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`. Anchors are added by default for string patterns by the `Validators.pattern` code.